# Can I find a class within the adminclass I'm in?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

```
// src/AdminBundle/Entity/RentalUnitAdmin.php
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        {
            $formMapper
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('location', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle:Location'))
                ->add('rentalUnitPriceGroups', 'collection', array(
                  'entry_type' => RentalUnitPriceGroupForm::class,
                  'entry_options' => array('rentalUnit' => $formMapper -> getFormBuilder() -> getData()),
                  'allow_add' => true,
                ))
                ->add('rentalCategory', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle:RentalCategory',
                  'choice_label' => 'name',))
            ;
        }
```

Is there any way to get the RentalUnit class without having to choose it manually via another adminclass, or is it even possible?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? You're using the ``RentalUnitAdmin`` and want a new instance of ``RentalUnit``?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know from the top of my head, but i believe you can do `$this->getSubject()`   or something along those lines.